# Clutch pedal became "springy" after installing new clutch

Tags: clutch

I've had clutch replaced on an old Suzuki Wagon R+ to a new aftermarket one. While it fixed the problems of changing gears I had, however, the clutch pedal is very stiff now. When pressing about halfway down - there's a lot of resistance. When releasing - it wants to jump back halfway up, which makes it very hard to catch the biting point and there's a high chance of stalling if you relax your foot. Problem exists even when the engine is not running.

Did the service do something wrong when installing the clutch? What could potentially be the cause of the problem?

Comment: What is the clutch operation mechanism? (cable, linkage, hydraulic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you've had an aftermarket clutch fitted.. If this is a performance clutch then it may well feel heavier and require more effort to press the pedal, this in turn makes it harder to feel the bitting point. It still should feel smooth though, just very springy, sven if heavy.

If its just a standard replacement clutch you've had, then it should feel smooth and operate down to the floor as normal. The bitting point may well feel different but it should still operate as expected.

If there is grinding or roughness of any sort, or the pedal won't go all the way down to the floor smoothly, then something is wrong either with the new clutch itself or it's fitment.. This requires further investigation.